# How to add relationship between two tables in Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: entity-framework-4, mapping

I have the following Requirement

I have a Table and corresponding entity in EF. Now my code is inserting Images to DB in the following table.

```
 PatientChartImages(
     PatientChartImageId guid,
     PatientChartId guid,
     NoOfImages int, 
     PatientChartImage varBinary(Max)
 )
```

I have to create a seperate table and store Images in it instead of PatientChartImages Table .

```
PatientChartImagesSource(
    PatientChartImageId,
    PatientChartImage varBinary(Max)
)
```

Is there a way in EntityFramework, So that whenever i refer to PatientChartImage  of PatientChartImages,PatientChartImage  of PatientChartImagesSource is referred. This way i won't have to change my DAL. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. This scenario is called [Entity splitting](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-entity-splitting/). You must create one-to-one relation on primary keys between PatientChartImages and PatientChartImagesSource to use it.